# Tomcat Unable to Read JNDI xml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jndi

I have just created a JNDI file for the spring boot application to read in the db info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/myapp" debug="0" reloadable="true">
    <Resource auth="Container" name="jdbc/myapp" 
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    password="password" 
    username="username"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.33:1521/xe" />
</Context>
```

But I have this error during startup of Tomcat 8 using the war file:

> java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 53; Document root element "Context", must match DOCTYPE root "null".

I think there is something wrong with the DOCTYPE. How should I specify it?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the initial `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` line.

Comment: Removed, but still the same problem.

Comment: _"JNDI file for the spring boot application"_: what file is that? The error suggests that Spring is expecting a [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file in XML format.

Comment: That file is what I have shown in the question. The filename ends with .xml

Comment: I meant: what is the name of the file? There is no standard way to configure JNDI resources in a Spring Boot application (JNDI resources are configured in the application server running the application). Do you start your project using an external Tomcat or the embedded one?

Comment: Name of the file is myapp.xml. I am using external Tomcat. And in my Spring app/WEB-INF/classes/config/application.yml, I have specified: spring:datasource:jndi-name: java:comp/env/jdbc/myapp

Comment: This is not a 'JNDI file'. It is a Tomcat Context file, to be deplyed in the META-INF folder of the webapp. Where are you deploying it to?

Comment: I am deploying it to TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost directory.